# Definir quais JFrames ficarão com foco?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Preciso deixar um `JFrame` em foco e não permitir utilizar os demais, enquanto eu não fechar esse.
Toda vez que abrir um novo Frame os demais abaixo dele devem ficar inoperantes.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Tipo tela inteira?

Answer (score 2):

Para isso, você deve criar um `JFrame` como tela principal, e demais telas como [**`JDialog`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), pois com ela, é possível criar janelas modais, onde somente a que foi aberta por ultimo ficará disponível para alteração.

Um dos construtores do `JDialog` recebe um container(Pode ser um Frame ou outro Dialog) do qual será "dependente", e um booleano informando se a janela será modal ou não. Através desses dois argumentos, você consegue controlar a relação entre as janelas, fazendo com que determinadas janelas só sejam acessíveis se suas dependentes não estiverem abertas.

Fiz um exemplo executável de como funciona.

Classe do JFrame principal:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ModalTeste extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ModalTeste().start());
    }

    private JFrame getInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    //start frames
    private void start() {
        setTitle("Frame principal");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnFrame = new JButton("Abrir Dialog");
        btnFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //passando a instancia do Frame para referencia do modal
                new Dialog01(getInstance()).start();
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Este é o frame principal"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnFrame, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
```

As classes abaixo representam duas JDialogs, onde a `Dialog01` é invocada no JFrame, e a `Dialog02` é invocada por `Dialog01`:

```
class Dialog01 extends JDialog {

    //precisa passar a janela mae como parametro para servir
    //de referencia ao modal
    public Dialog01(JFrame owner) {
        //recebe a janela mae, o titulo(opcional) e se é modal
        super(owner, "Dialog 01", true);
    }

    private JDialog getInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    public void start() {
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Abrir outro dialog");
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //aqui está sendo passada a instancia do Dialog01
                //como referencia do modal da dialog02
                new Dialog02(getInstance()).start();
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Esta é a primeira janela modal"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btn2,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

```java
class Dialog02 extends JDialog {

    // repare que o Jdialog pode receber um JFrame ou
    // outro JDialog como argumento
    public Dialog02(Dialog owner) {
        // recebe a janela mae, o titulo e se é modal
        super(owner, "Dialog 02", true);
    }

    public void start() {

        add(new JLabel("Esta é a segunda janela modal"));
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Referência:**

[How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)