# Preencher campo de texto com retorno de outra janela

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Tenho um `JTextField` instanciado na classe **rel_tempo**. Ao clicar nesse `JTextField`, ele chama um outro `JFrame` de buscas.
Ao realizar uma busca neste novo `JFrame` e clicar em *Confirmar*, preciso que ele preencha o `JTextField` do primeiro Frame.

Tentei de algumas formas, deixando os jtextfields publicos e com o seguinte código:

```
relatorio.txt_id.setText(txt_id.getText());
```

Tentei criar um metodo na primeira JFrame onde está o JtextField que recebe por parametro os dados

Nenhuma das tentativas que fiz preencheu o JTextField, como faço isso?

Chamada da tela de pesquisa:

```
 private void txt_idMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    busca busca = new busca(null, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
    busca.setVisible(true);
}
```

Classe tela de pesquisa:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

public class busca extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private List list_atendentes;

    public busca(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        listar_pessoas();
    }

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Criteria crit_pessoa = session.createCriteria(Pessoa.class);
        crit_pessoa.add(Restrictions.like("nome", "%"+txt_nome.getText()+"%"));
        list_atendentes = crit_pessoa.list();
        TableModelBusca tm = new TableModelBusca(list_atendentes);
        table.setModel(tm);
    }                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        rel_tempo relatorio = new rel_tempo(null, rootPaneCheckingEnabled);
        relatorio.txt_id.setText(txt_id.getText());
        relatorio.txt_nome.setText(txt_nome.getText());
        dispose();
    }                                        

     public void listar_pessoas() throws HibernateException {
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Criteria crit_motivo = session.createCriteria(Pessoa.class);
        list_atendentes = crit_motivo.list();
        TableModelBusca tm = new TableModelBusca(list_atendentes);
        table.setModel(tm);
    }

}
```

Comment: Usando JDialog, ao inves de outro JFrame, seus problemas são reduzidos em 90%. Poste a chamada da tela de pesquisa e a classe da tela de pesquisa, que posso até sugerir tal alteração em código.

Comment: Editei, da uma olhada @diegofm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você transformou sua segunda tela(Busca) em `JDialog`, crie um atributo nela que irá guardar o texto que você quer retornar:

```
private String strId;
private String strNome;
```

Para facilitar o retorno, crie um método que retorne um vetor de Strings, assim, é possível retornar os dois valores juntos. Se preferir, crie get pra cada um e retorne-os separados

```
private String[] retornarTextos(){
  String[] valores = {txt_id.getText(), txt_nome.getText()};
  return valores;
}
```

No evento do botão que encerrará a atividade da tela de busca, não há necessidade de instanciar a tela principal novamente, basta atribuir o valor que você quer retornar as variáveis que acabamos de criar:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    strId = txt_id.getText());
    strNome = txt_nome.getText();
    dispose();
}
```

Na tela principal, ao estanciar a tela de busca, esta deve receber como parâmetros a propria instância de sua tela principal(ela será o *owner*) e `true`, para que a tela de busca fique sobreposta à tela principal, bloqueando-a até a busca ser fechada(característica modal). Para recuperar os valores digitados, basta chamar o método criado na Tela de busca logo após o `setVisible`:

```
private void txt_idMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    //passe a instancia da tela principal(rel_tempo)
    busca busca = new busca(seuFrame, true);
    busca.setVisible(true);
    String[] textosDigitados = busca.retornarTextos();
    //O id foi o primeiro indice a ser preenchido na outra classe
    //por isso o indice 0
    txt_id.setText(textosDigitados[0]);

}
```

Se preferir usar *getters* pra retornar os valores dos campos da segunda tela, basta chamá-los diretamente no `setText` dos campos da tela principal.

---

Referências com exemplos de uso das JDialogs:

[How to Make Dialogs/Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

[Definir quais JFrames ficarão com foco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126315/definir-quais-jframes-ficar%C3%A3o-com-foco/126351#126351)