# Minimizar aplicação para a bandeja do sistema

Tags: java, swing, system-tray

Fiz uma aplicação conforme solicitada por um cliente, porém no final do projeto o mesmo me informou que a aplicação deve abrir em Tray Icon, e ao minimizada continuar em execução em tray

Minha aplicação já está toda desenvolvida, o tray icon não precisa ter opções, apenas ficar minimizado e ao dar dois cliques retornar a tela principal da aplicação.

Tentei de algumas formas porém não entendi o funcionamento.

Como faço para implementar isto?

Comment: Que tipo de aplicação? Swing, javafx?

Comment: Aplicação Swing @diegofm

Comment: Ela deve permanecer o tempo todo no SystemTRay? Mesmo quando estiver visivel, ou minimizada?

Comment: Somente quando estiver minimizada @diegofm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa trabalhar com as classes [**`SystemTray`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) e com status da janela, utilizando [**`WindowListeners`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html).

Com a primeira classe você verifica se o sistema suporta adição de aplicações na bandeja do sistema. Utilizando a classe [**`TrayIcon`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html), é possível criar um ícone que será exibido. E na segunda classe você monitora quando a janela será minimizada, para que seja *"iconificada"* para a bandeja, e quando a janela é reaberta, para que o *iconTray* saia de lá.

Fiz um exemplo executável e comentado nos pontos mais importantes do código.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FrameMinimizadoTest {

    public void start() throws IOException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Frame principal");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);

        JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(field);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //checa se o sistema tem suporte a iconTray
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            //pega uma instancia da bandeija do sistema
            final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            //apenas para demonstração, altere para a imagem da
            //sua aplicação
            Image icon = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/tick-icon-2.png"));
            //frame.setIconImage(icon);
            //cria um icone de bandeira, recebendo uma imagem 
            final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(icon);
            //IMPORTANTE! Deixa a propria API
            //decidir o tamanho, se remover essa linha
            //não aceitará imagem de qualquer tamanho
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

            //adiciona uma ação ao frame, para monitorar alterações de status
            //da janela
            frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                    //checa se a janela foi minimizada
                    if (e.getNewState() == JFrame.ICONIFIED) {
                        //listener para que a janela se abra com
                        //o clique do mouse
                        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                                frame.toFront();
                                //remove o icone da bandeira
                                //quando a janela for reaberta
                                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            tray.add(trayIcon);
                        } catch (AWTException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FrameMinimizadoTest f = new FrameMinimizadoTest();
                try {
                    f.start();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Referências:**

- [How do I put a Java app in the system tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758083/5524514)
- [How to hide a JFrame in system tray of taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7461477/5524514)
- [Java.awt.SystemTray does not display tray icon properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820255/5524514)
- [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)
- [How to Use the System Tray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: Tu é o cara, admiro sua vontade de ajudar hehehehe

Comment: @ViniciusLeonardo estamos ai pra ajudar mesmo :). Aproveita e da uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/140238/28595), se tiver algo errado, me avisa que corrijo la.