# Abrir várias janelas da mesma aplicação sem acumular icones na barra de tarefas

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia criar frames em java, sem que fossem abertos tantas janelas na barra de tarefas do windows.

Por exemplo quando eu vou no menu e clico em cadastro de clientes, cadastro de endereços, cadastro de tipos de endereços, são abertas 3 janelas, sendo que é um mesmo sistema. Como fazer que apareça apenas um icone da aplicação na barra de tarefas, mesmo com várias janelas abertas?

Comment: "Melhor maneira" torna a pergunta opinativa.

Comment: Ou qual uma forma de não abrir tantas janelas na barra do windows? Dialogs?

Comment: Editei, veja se não alterou sua linha de raciocinio.

Comment: Eu entendi, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já respondi algo parecido [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126315/28595), quando se tem várias janelas em uma mesma aplicação, o mais recomendado é usar [**`JDialog`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) para janelas secundárias, e `JFrame` apenas para a janela principal, pois através do `JDialog` você consegue ter mais controle de qual janela estará em foco, a troca de dados entre janelas é facilitado pois, enquanto a *JDialog* está aberta, as outras janelas ficam travadas<sup>1</sup> para seleção, aguardando o termino da operação nela. Claro que isso exige um certo controle de hierarquia entre as janelas.

*<sup>1- somente se a ModalityType não for Modeless, que deixa as outras janelas livres para alteração.</sup>*

No código abaixo, retirado da outra pergunta, tem um exemplo executável de como funcionam as *JDialogs*, e o controle entre elas.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ModalTeste extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ModalTeste().start());
    }

    private JFrame getInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    //start frames
    private void start() {
        setTitle("Frame principal");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnFrame = new JButton("Abrir Dialog");
        btnFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //passando a instancia do Frame para referencia do modal
                Dialog01 d1 = new Dialog01(getInstance());
                d1.start();
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Este é o frame principal"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnFrame, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    class Dialog01 extends JDialog {

        //precisa passar a janela mae como parametro para servir
        //de referencia ao modal
        public Dialog01(JFrame owner) {
            //recebe a janela mae, o titulo(opcional) e se é modal
            super(owner, "Dialog 01", true);
        }

        private JDialog getInstance() {
            return this;
        }

        private void start() {
            JButton btn2 = new JButton("Abrir outro dialog");
            btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //aqui está sendo passada a instancia do Dialog01
                    //como referencia do modal da dialog02
                    Dialog02 d2 = new Dialog02(getInstance());
                    d2.start();
                }
            });
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("Esta é a primeira janela modal"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(btn2,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            setSize(200, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
            setVisible(true);
        }

    }

    class Dialog02 extends JDialog {

        //repare que o Jdialog pode receber um JFrame ou
        //outro JDialog como argumento
        public Dialog02(Dialog owner) {
            //recebe a janela mae, o titulo e se é modal
            super(owner, "Dialog 02", true);
        }

        private void start() {

            add(new JLabel("Esta é a segunda janela modal"));
            setSize(200, 200);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deixa eu te fazer uma outra pergunta, Quando eu apertar Alt + tab, sair e voltar como posso saber em qual dialog estava o foco quando não são modais, esse é o maior problema que eu enfrento, quando não utilizo frames e sim dialogs. o que acontece é que quando eu volto o foco vai para o frame e não para a dialog

Comment: @UlissesGimenes bom isso já é uma duvida bem diferente da pergunta, mas como disse na pergunta, isso pode ser controlado pela hierarquia, execute o código e verá um exemplo, a dialog01 pertence ao frame, a dialog02 pertence a dialog1, assim você controla a ordem.

Comment: Acontece o mesmo problema nela, a unica forma e que se ela não é modal, ou seja não passo true, o foco volta para o frame. Você acha melhor eu fazer outra pergunta referente assunto?

Comment: @UlissesGimenes se você quer abrir várias janelas, pra que quer que o foco fique na primeira? Não faz muito sentido nisso.

Comment: Na verdade quando eu sair e voltar gostaria que o foco voltasse justamente para  a janela que estava o foco, por exemplo: eu estava na Dialog02, apertei alt + tab para fazer algo no windows, quando voltar novamente com alt + tab gostaria que foco fosse para a dialog02 e nao para o frame, será que você entende a minha dúvida?

Comment: Da forma que peguei o sistema já estava assim e não usa dialogs com modal true, por exemplo eu estou no cadastro de clientes e precisaria de uma informação de outra janela se for modal não tem como acessar a outra janela para pegar alguma informação.

Comment: @UlissesGimenes se você desligar o modal, as chances de pegar informação desatualizada entre as janelas serão grandes. E modais sempre ficam acima das janelas-pai. Logo, a janela inferior jamais ficará acima. O que você pode fazer é abrir as dialogs ao lado do frame, assim, não ficam sobrepondo.

Comment: O que acontece e que o tonto do meu patrão pra não dizer pior porque é uma íngua,  acha que sabe alguma coisa e fica copiando outro sistema, e fica me enchendo a paciência. porque tem um tal de SIAGRI aqui que faz isso, só que ele é feito em Delphi, e ele faz isso que mencionei. So que não tem como saber como ele faz isso porque eu não tenho acesso ao código fonte. mas vou deixando essa dúvida por enquanto.. obrigado pela paciência..

Comment: @UlissesGimenes tenta da forma que te falei antes, botando as janelas lado a lado, sao janelas muito grandes? Estou tentando alterar o exemplo colocando as janelas lado a lado aqui, quando terminar, atualizo a resposta.

Comment: @UlissesGimenes infelizmente o link não abre aqui na rede onde estou. Mas você já conseguiu fazer as dialogs abrirem lado a lado, sem ter que arrastar?

Comment: @UlissesGimenes bom, parece ser uma duvida mais complexa que a da pergunta. É bom fazer outra pergunta, adicionando um [mcve] do seu código para que seja possível simular o problema e marque essa como resolvida, talvez em outra pergunta, você obtenha mais sugestões que te ajude nesse outra problema :)

Comment: Obrigado, pelas respostas