# Modificar JOptionPane

Tags: java

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Opá pessoal, estou personalizando meus componentes do swing, tem como modificar o JOptionPane? de maneira que fiquei bem diferente ? ex: retirar a barra com titulo e a opção de fecha e etc...

Comment: Isso não é possivel, joptionpane é uma janela modal com funcionalidades basicas, justamente pra quem quer algo simples sem muita personalização. Se quer personalizar, vejas as duplicadas que mostram o que é possivel personalizar, agora se quer criar uma versao propria, veja os dois links abaixo onde explico a respeito de JDialog, que sao janelas modais para voce criar como bem entender.

Comment: [Abrir várias janelas da mesma aplicação sem acumular icones na barra de tarefas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142609/28595)

Comment: [Definir quais JFrames ficarão com foco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126315/28595)